# CSP issues when trying to construct a web worker

Tags: web-worker, electron-forge, content-security-policy

Im Constructing a web worker in an Electron-Forge project.

I have defined a CSP rule for a web worker like this:

```
 import { session } from "electron"
 session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
        responseHeaders: {
            ...details.responseHeaders,
            'Content-Security-Policy': [
               
                'worker-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\' blob:'
            ]
        }
    })
})
```

I keep getting the error:

> Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at
> 'blob:http://localhost:3000/56a59311-87f4-4493-81ab-3d86f46bf0cb' is
> denied by the document's Content Security Policy.

The way im constructing the web worker :

```
 class WorkerBuilder extends Worker {
    constructor(worker) {
    const code = worker.toString();
    const blob = new Blob(["(" + code + ")()"]);
    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}

const worker  = new WebWorker(....)
```

Whats wrong with my CSP rules?
It has to work both in dev and prod.

Comment: Are there multiple policies set? Check if there are other response headers or meta tags setting a content-securitp-policy.